# State is not getting updated in Function Component using useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update `state` in a `function component`.

It seems that here I am having an issue. Please, tell why it is giving error?

**Code-Snippet:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const HomeFunctional = () => {

  const [details, setDetails] = useState({name: "Jack Rogers", age: 29, city: "New York"});

  alpha = () => {
    setDetails({name: "Julious Cezer", age: 59, city: "Rome"});
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Home Functional!</p>
      <p>{details.name + "/" + details.age + "/" + details.city} </p>
      <button onClick={this.alpha}>Change Values</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeFunctional;
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: You're in an arrow function, which doesn't have this. alpha isn't a property on anything, it's a local variable in the function.

Comment: but in last question, you asked to make use of arrow function. :-/

Comment: Can you please help out with correct code?

Comment: Oh it's you again. Yes, but you've also completely changed to a functional component. It's not clear why you thought this.alpha would be defined, at a basic JS syntax level alpha is just a variable.

Comment: Also note this question again shows no research effort. And given the elapsed time, it's clear that's because you didn't do any.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : One more question. In 'class based component' (last question) I did not need to put `const` infront of alpha, but here in `functional component` why am I forced to write `const` infront of function? -- as per right solution of `abdullah` below.

Comment: Because class definitions and function bodies are totally different things. Again, a structured JS tutorial will help you understand the basic syntax that React and other libraries build on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using a functional component you have to write `const alpha`

```
 const alpha = () => {
```

and instead of using `this.alpha` you would just write `alpha`.

```
 <button onClick={alpha}>Change Values</button>
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-monad-qe16m)

Comment: It needs atleast 10 min before I can accept bro! :) ... cheers.